# Why are relations not being added to my loopback.io objects in the models?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I am quite new to Loopback and NodeJS, so please tell me if there is a "Node way" of doing something that I am missing. I decided to write a basic application to try and learn more.

I have two models, 'UserInformation' and 'ClothingArticle'. I have created a 'hasMany' relation from UserInformation to ClothingArticle.

As a basic test, I wanted to add a remote method to UserInformation to get recommendations for ClothingArticles. However, I cannot seem to get access to anything related to ClothingArticles. I added code into the common/models/user-information.js file to try and retrieve information about the relation, but am not sure if this is even the right spot to be putting it.

My code is below, could you help?

common/models/user-information.js:

```
module.exports = function(UserInformation) {

    get_methods = function(obj) {
        var result = [];
        for(var id in obj) {
            try {
                if(typeof(obj[id]) == "function") {
                    result.push(id + " (function): "); //+ obj[id].toString());
                }
                else
                    result.push(id + ": "); // + obj[id].toString());
            }
            catch (err) {
                result.push(id + ": inaccessible");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    // This doesn't anything about my new relations?
    console.log(get_methods(UserInformation.prototype));

    UserInformation.recommendations = function(source, callback) {
        var response = "I don't have any recommendations.";

        var test_function = UserInformation.findById(3, function(err, instances) {
            if(err) return console.log("Errors: " + err);

            console.log("Instances: " + String(instances));

            // Nothing here either about the relations.
            console.log(get_methods(UserInformation));
            console.log(UserInformation.app);
            /*
            instances.clothingArticles.create({
                id:92,
                colors:['red','blue']
            });
    */
            console.log("Created a new clothing article.");
        });

        console.log (response);
        callback(null, response);
    }

    UserInformation.remoteMethod(
        'recommendations',
        {
            accepts: [
                {arg: 'source', type: 'string'} // Used to mark the source (closet, generic, etc)
            ],
            http: {path: '/recommendations', verb: 'get'},
            returns: {arg: 'recommendations', type: 'string'}
        }
    );
};
```

common/models/user-information.json:

```
{
  "name": "UserInformation",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": false,
  "idInjection": false,
  "properties": {
    "birthday": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true,
      "required": true
    },
    "eye_color": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "hair_color": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "weight": {
      "type": "string",
      "comments": "pounds"
    },
    "height": {
      "type": "number",
      "comments": "inches"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "clothingArticles": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "ClothingArticle",
      "foreignKey": "owner_id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

common/models/clothing-article.json:

```
{
  "name": "ClothingArticle",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": false,
  "idInjection": false,
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "number",
      "id": true,
      "required": true
    },
    "colors": {
      "type": [
        "Color"
      ],
      "required": true
    },
    "owner_id": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

Comment: what is null in callback(null, response);

Comment: I assumed it was the error, if there was one. I eventually gave up on using Loopback.io and just went to Mean.js instead. The docs and examples were much more clear, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting with our [getting started example](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-getting-started) and working your way through through the tutorial series here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example

The questions you ask are answered throughout the examples (ie. model relations). To answer your question, if you defined a relation properly, you should be able to access the relation via dot.

```
...
UserInformation.ClothingArticle...
...
```

See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/HasMany+relations for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I read through the docs and the examples, but none of the examples that I found actually _used_ data through a relation. They declared it in the model JSON, but never actually accessed it anywhere in the sample. I also ran get_methods() on UserInformation and did not see any references to ClothingArticle. Any ideas on how to do some more debugging of it?

Comment: I agree, we need an example repo specifically to demonstrate model relations without REST. For now, you can see an example in this repo https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control/blob/master/server/boot/sample-models.js#L17

You can see we use the `user`'s relation to `projects` being accessed. Also look in `common/models/*.json and look at the defined relations.

Comment: That is more of what I was looking for, thank you! The code is based in server/boot, but can you use model relations like that inside the commond/model/<name>.js file directly? Or is that file only for describing the global model, rather than using instances of the model?

Comment: > can you use model relations like that inside the commond/model/<name>.js file directly

Yes, that's exactly it. Anywhere you can access `app.models.ModelName`, you can access its relations.